# How to restrict a user to not be able to input a 0 in c

Tags: c

I have the following function to filter integer values and re-prompt the user.

```
int checkInput0(void){
    int option0,check0;
    char c;

    do{
        printf("Enter the amount of triangles you want to check: \n");

        if(scanf("%d%c",&option0,&c) == 0 || c != '\n'){
            while((check0 = getchar()) != 0 && check0 != '\n' && check0 != EOF);
            printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    // printf("returning the value of option, which is %f", option);
    return option0;
```

However, I would like to extend this function to filter 0 as well.

I seem to be missing something. All help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The return from scanf is the number of items successfully filled. You're not using it correctly.

Comment: `...c != '\n' || option0 <= 0`

Comment: in the `if` statement, add a check `|| option0 == 0`.  Incidentally, since you are reading two values using `scanf()`, it is possible that `scanf()` returns `0`, `1`, `2`, or `EOF`.   If it returns `1`, `c` has not been modified - which will cause undefined behaviour on the first loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

the posted code is not checking the returned value from 'scanf()' correctly and doesn't quite perform the desired functionality.

The following proposed code:

1. clarifies the logic
2. properly checks for I/O errors
3. discards invalid input
4. exits the program if the I/O failed
5. separates the inputting of data from the emptying of 'stdin'

and now the proposed code:

```
do
{
    printf("Enter the amount of triangles you want to check: \n");

    if( scanf( "%d", &option0 ) == 1 )
    {
        if( 0 >= option0 )
        {  // 0 or negative value entered
            printf("[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n");
            continue;
        }

        // empty stdin
        while( (check0 = getchar()) != EOF && check0 != '\n' );

        // exit while() loop
        break;
    }

    else
    { // scanf failed
        perror( "scanf for number of triangles failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
} while(1);
```